# Reference Error: menu.show is undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a html file with a button.My html file loads main.js as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My Account</title>
 <!-- RequireJS bootstrap file -->
    <script data-main="lib/main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>First name: <input data-bind="value:firstName"/></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value:lastName"/></p>
<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
<button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Main.js loads another application js called menu.js which has a function called show.
On click of the button, i am calling this function show as follow:

Main.js is defined as:

```
requirejs.config({
//Path mappings for the logical module names

paths: {
'knockout': 'jslibs/knockout-2.3.0',
'jquery': 'jslibs/jquery-1.11.0',
'menu':'jslibs/menu'
},

// Shim configurations for modules that do not expose AMD
shim: {
    'jquery': {
        exports: ['jQuery', '$']
    }

    },
});

require(['jquery','knockout','menu'],
function($,ko) {   
  function AppViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.firstName = ko.observable("");
      self.lastName = ko.observable("");
      self.fullName = ko.computed(function (){
         return this.firstName() +" "+this.lastName();
            },this);

       this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
           menu.show(); 
            };
        };
vm= new AppViewModel();
$(document).ready(function() {  
ko.applyBindings(vm);   
});});
```

menu.js is defined as:

```
define(['jquery','knockout'],function($,ko){ 
var add = {
        show: function(id) {
            alert('inside show');

        }
     };

return add;     
});
```

On the button click, I am getting error:

**ReferenceError: menu is not defined**

menu.show();

Any pointer? I have checked the path and all the paths are valid.

Thanks
Tanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **menu** in the args as well here:

```
function($,ko, menu) {
```

---

Because its not available in the parent functions scope so it results in a **ReferenceError: menu is not defined**, as you are using **menu** in the child function and you have put the `$, ko` in the args but you forgot to pass `menu` too in the args.